# How to send message to a particular client using SignalR

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

If I have multiple clients connected to hub, how would I get the details of all the connected clients from client side(.aspx) using JavaScript.
In the `SendChatMessage()` method, I have to pass "who" parameter from the client side(.aspx) but how would I get to know the connection Id or username of the a particular clients among so many connected clients.

```
public class Chathub : Hub
{
    private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections =
        new ConnectionMapping<string>();

    public void SendChatMessage(string who, string message)
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
        {
            Clients.Client(connectionId).addChatMessage(name + ": "message);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
        return base.OnConnected();
    }


 public class ConnectionMapping<T>
 {
    private readonly Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>> _connections =
        new Dictionary<T, HashSet<string>>();

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _connections.Count;
        }
    }

    public void Add(T key, string connectionId)
    {
        lock (_connections)
        {
            HashSet<string> connections;
            if (!_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
            {
                connections = new HashSet<string>();
                _connections.Add(key, connections);
            }

            lock (connections)
            {
                connections.Add(connectionId);
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetConnections(T key)
    {
        HashSet<string> connections;
        if (_connections.TryGetValue(key, out connections))
        {
            return connections;
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add the C# tag to this question? It seems to relate more to that than JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

While sending message to specific client, you have to call `chathub.server.sendMessage()` from client

```
public void SendPrivateMessage(string toUserId, string message)
        {

            string fromUserId = Context.ConnectionId;

            var toUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == toUserId) ;
            var fromUser = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == fromUserId);

            if (toUser != null && fromUser!=null)
            {
                // send to 
                Clients.Client(toUserId).sendMessage(fromUserId, fromUser.UserName, message); 

                // send to caller user as well to update caller chat
                Clients.Caller.sendMessage(toUserId, fromUser.UserName, message); 
            }

        }
```

`Clients.Caller.sendMessage(toUserId, fromUser.UserName, message);` note that this is client method, to update the chat.

Then in client side, call `chathub.server.sendMessage(id,msg)`
where you can pass `id` of that `specific user`
To get id you have to use jQuery, e.g first you have to save id of each client in client side lets say

```
<a id='userid' class="username"></a>
```

and on click event you can get the `id` of that user like

```
    $("a").on('click',function(){

    var touser = $(this).attr('id'))
    }

chathub.server.sendMeassage(touser,msg);
```

This may not the complete solution, but you have to do like this.

There's good post [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/562023/asp-net-signalr-chat-room?fid=1828320&df=90&mpp=50&prof=true&sort=Position&view=Topic&spc=Compact&fr=76) which shows the idea.

Comment: In the SendChatMessage() method, what to pass in place of "who" as parameter from client side. I think "who" is working as a key for my dictionary(dictionary containing the details of connected clients) which is to be used to find the ConnectionId having that key..

Comment: check edits, you have to do this in order to implement your requirement.